# Is it possible to change the icon from my app's Quick Search Box?

Tags: android

So I have implemented my application's [Quick Search Box](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html). Everything is going fine, but the icon that appears on the left side of the search box is my application's launcher icon. But I would like to customize it dynamically. 
I would like to know if it's possible, and if so, how can I achieve?

Thanks in advance.